# DDD: Is there an elegant way to pass auditing information through while updating an aggregate root?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, cqrs, auditing

Suppose I have a CQRS command that looks like below:

```
public sealed class DoSomethingCommand : IRequest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public string A { get; set; }

    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

That's processed in the following command handler:

```
public sealed class DoSomethingCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<DoSomethingCommand, Unit>
{
    private readonly IAggregateRepository _aggregateRepository;

    public DoSomethingCommand(IAggregateRepository aggregateRepository)
    {
       _aggregateRepository = aggregateRepository;
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(DoSomethingCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Find aggregate from id in request
        var id = new AggregateId(request.Id);

        var aggregate = await _aggregateRepository.GetById(id);

        if (aggregate == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        // Translate request properties into a value object relevant to the aggregate
        var something = new AggregateValueObject(request.A, request.B);

        // Get the aggregate to do whatever the command is meant to do and save the changes
        aggregate.DoSomething(something);

        await _aggregateRepository.Save(aggregate);

        return Unit.Value;
    }
}
```

I have a requirement to save auditing information such as the "CreatedByUserID" and "ModifiedByUserID". This is a purely technical concern because none of my business logic is dependent on these fields.

I've found a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218352/when-to-update-audit-fields-ddd/12407456#12407456), where there was a suggestion to raise an event to handle this. This would be a nice way to do it because I'm also persisting changes based on the domain events raised from an aggregate using an approach similar to the one described [here](https://www.erikheemskerk.nl/ddd-persistence-recorded-event-driven-persistence/).

*(TL;DR: Add events into a collection in the aggregate for every action, pass the aggregate to a single `Save` method in the repository, use pattern matching in that repository method to handle each event type stored in the aggregate to persist the changes)*

e.g.
The `DoSomething` behavior from above would look something like this:

```
public void DoSomething(AggregateValueObject something)
{
    // Business logic here
    ...

    // Add domain event to a collection
    RaiseDomainEvent(new DidSomething(/* required information here */));
}
```

The `AggregateRepository` would then have methods that looked like this:

```
public void Save(Aggregate aggregate)
{
   var events = aggregate.DequeueAllEvents();

   DispatchAllEvents(events);
}

private void DispatchAllEvents(IReadOnlyCollection<IEvent> events)
{
    foreach (var @event in events)
    {
        DispatchEvent((dynamic) @event);
    }
}

private void Handle(DidSomething @event)
{
    // Persist changes from event
}
```

As such, adding a `RaisedByUserID` to each domain event seems like a good way to allow each event handler in the repository to save the "CreatedByUserID" or "ModifiedByUserID". It also seems like good information to have when persisting domain events in general.

My question is related to whether there is an easy to make the `UserId` from the `DoSomethingCommand` flow down into the domain event or whether I should even bother doing so.

At the moment, I think there are two ways to do this:

**Option 1:**

Pass the `UserId` into every single use case on an aggregate, so it can be passed into the domain event.

e.g.

The `DoSomething` method from above would change like so:

```
public void DoSomething(AggregateValueObject something, Guid userId)
{
    // Business logic here
    ...

    // Add domain event to a collection
    RaiseDomainEvent(new DidSomething(/* required information here */, userId));
}
```

The disadvantage to this method is that the user ID really has nothing to do with the domain, yet it needs to be passed into every single use case on every single aggregate that needs the auditing fields.

**Option 2:**

Pass the `UserId` into the repository's `Save` method instead. This approach would avoid introducing irrelevant details to the domain model, even though the repetition of requiring a `userId` parameter on all the event handlers and repositories is still there.

e.g.

The `AggregateRepository` from above would change like so:

```
public void Save(Aggregate aggregate, Guid userId)
{
   var events = aggregate.DequeueAllEvents();

   DispatchAllEvents(events, userId);
}

private void DispatchAllEvents(IReadOnlyCollection<IEvent> events, Guid userId)
{
    foreach (var @event in events)
    {
        DispatchEvent((dynamic) @event, Guid userId);
    }
}

private void Handle(DidSomething @event, Guid userId)
{
    // Persist changes from event and use user ID to update audit fields
}
```

This makes sense to me as the `userId` is used for a purely technical concern, but it still has the same repetitiveness as the first option. It also doesn't allow me to encapsulate a "RaisedByUserID" in the immutable domain event objects, which seems like a nice-to-have.

**Option 3:**

Could there be any better ways of doing this or is the repetition really not that bad?

I considered adding a `UserId` field to the repository that can be set before any actions, but that seems bug-prone even if it removes all the repetition as it would need to be done in every command handler.

Could there be some magical way to achieve something similar through dependency injection or a decorator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend on the concrete case. I'll try to explain couple of different problems and their solutions.

1. You have a system where the auditing information is naturally part of the domain.

Let's take a simple example:

A banking system that makes contracts between the *Bank* and a *Person*. The *Bank* is represented by a *BankEmployee*. When a *Contract* is either signed or modified you need to include the information on who did it in the contract.

```
public class Contract {

    public void AddAdditionalClause(BankEmployee employee, Clause clause) {
        AddEvent(new AdditionalClauseAdded(employee, clause));
    }
}
```

2. You have a system where the auditing information is not natural part of the domain.

There are couple of things here that need to be addressed. For example can users only issue commands to your system? Sometimes another system can invoke commands.

*Solution:* Record all incomming commands and their status after processing: successful, failed, rejected etc.

Include the information of the command issuer.

Record the time when the command occured. You can include the information about the issuer in the command or not.

```
public interface ICommand {
    public Datetime Timestamp { get; private set; }
}

public class CommandIssuer {
    public CommandIssuerType Type { get; pivate set; }
    public CommandIssuerInfo Issuer {get; private set; }
}

public class CommandContext {
    public ICommand cmd { get; private set; }
    public CommandIssuer CommandIssuer { get; private set; }
}

public class CommandDispatcher {

    public void Dispatch(ICommand cmd, CommandIssuer issuer){

        LogCommandStarted(issuer, cmd);

        try {
            DispatchCommand(cmd);
            LogCommandSuccessful(issuer, cmd);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            LogCommandFailed(issuer, cmd, ex);
        }
    }

    // or
    public void Dispatch(CommandContext ctx) {
        // rest is the same
    }
}
```

*pros*: This will remove your domain from the knowlegde that someone issues commands

*cons*: If you need more detailed information about the changes and match commands to events you will need to match timestamps and other information. Depending on the complexity of the system this may get ugly

*Solution:* Record all incomming commands in the entity/aggregate with the corresponding events. Check [this article](https://jimmybogard.com/life-beyond-transactions-implementation-primer/) for a detailed example. You can include the `CommandIssuer` in the events.

```
public class SomethingAggregate {

    public void Handle(CommandCtx ctx) {
        RecordCommandIssued(ctx);
        Process(ctc.cmd);
    }
}
```

You do include some information from the outside to your aggregates, but at least it's abstracted, so the aggregate just records it. It doesn't look so bad, does it?

*Solution:* Use a saga that will contain all the information about the operation you are using. In a distributed system, most of the time you will need to do this so it whould be a good solution. In another system it will add complexity and an overhead that you maaaay not wan't to have :)

```
public void DoSomethingSagaCoordinator {

    public void Handle(CommandContext cmdCtx) {

        var saga = new DoSomethingSaga(cmdCtx);
        sagaRepository.Save(saga);
        saga.Process();
        sagaRepository.Update(saga);
    }
}
```

I've used all methods described here and also a variation of your **Option 2**. In my version when a request was handled, the `Repositoires` had access to a `context` that conained the user info, so when they saved events this information was included in `EventRecord` object that had both the event data and the user info. It was automated, so the rest of the code was decoupled from it. I did used DI to inject the contex to the repositories. In this case I was just recording the events to an event log. My aggregates were not event sourced.

I use these guidelines to choose an approach:

If its a distributed system -> go for Saga

If it's not:

Do I need to relate detailed information to the command?

- Yes: pass `Commands` and/or `CommandIssuer` info to aggregates

If no then:

Does the dabase has good transactional support?

- Yes: save `Commands`and `CommandIssuer`outside of aggregates.
- No: save `Commands`and `CommandIssuer` in aggreages.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful. I think the repository method with a context may suit my needs and database. It looks like injecting `IPrincipal` for .NET Core might give me what I need from some quick research, but I haven't implemented it yet so can't say for sure.

Comment: You're welcome :) In our case it wasn't a .NET Core project, so I can't help you with more info or concrete implementation.